# Python: How to resume the python script as soon as vpn network is up?

Tags: python, automation, subprocess, vpn

I have a python script (xyz.py) that I run through the command prompt. My question is that don't we have any method which helps to resume the python code automatically from where it was lost the VPN connection, without any manual intervention. This will help to avoid monitoring the code frequently. Below is my code but it reads from the start if there is any disconnection. Please suggest.

```
filename = 'xyz.py'
while True:
    p = subprocess.Popen('python '+filename, shell=True).wait()
"""  #if your there is an error from running 'xyz.py', 
     the while loop will be repeated, 
    otherwise the program will break from the loop"""
   if p != 0:
      continue
   else:
      break
```

Comment: As an aside, running Python as a subprocess of itself is often something you want to avoid. There are situations where it's useful or even necessary, but very often you will get more control over the flow if you `import` the code into your current script and call its functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

If me, `time.sleep` will be used:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

import requests


script = 'xyz.py'

def main():
    network_check_url = 'http://8.8.8.8'
    while True:
        try:
            requests.get(network_check_url)
        except Exception as e:
            print(datetime.now(), e)
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print('Network is ok. {datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}')
            os.system(f'python {script}')
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use ip address in place of  'network_check_url' for connection ? How that can be implemented ?

Comment: Depends on what sort of network check you want to implement. I can't fetch `http://8.8.8.8/` from here either so I think it's just meant as a placeholder for something more useful. `requests.get()` with just an IP address will get you a URL syntax error so you probably want to change the method to something else (but your question sounds like you will probably need help articulating something which is actually well-defined).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when I lost vpn connection, this program stops. But my request is to wait for the network to up and then continue automatically. In this case, it completely stops.

Comment: Please suggest how to continue the script automatically if network regains the connection.

Comment: The code as such does attempt again and again, but it probably takes significantly longer than you expect for it to time out. When the network is down, you should expect the `try:` to take something like 60-180 seconds, depending also on various network configuration parameters etc.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. But this code is not helping to re-run the script automatically , if network disconnect and connects again. You can test this program at your end.